# Database - Multilanguage online dictionary

Tags: database, multilingual

I am implementing a database for a multilanguage online dictionary. At the moment I have only 2 languages (RO - Romanian, CS - Czech), but I think maybe in future I will want to add more languages (for example EN - english).

The website will be multilanguage too, so a romanian user can look for czech words and a czech user can look for romanian words.

I'm thinking how could I implement the `TRANSLATIONS` table for multiple translations. At the moment I have this implementation, but it's not the way to go, because in case I will add another 10 languages, I would have to add another 10 columns:

```
WORD (id,word,language_id,..)
TRANSLATIONS(id,ro_id,cs_id)
LANGUAGE(id,code)

LANGUAGE
id   code
1     ro
2     cs

WORD

id word language_id
1  xxx      1
2  yyy      2

TRANSLATIONS
id   ro_id   cs_id
1      1       2
```

I could make a table like:

```
TRANSLATIONS(id,word_id,translation_id)
```

but in this case I don't know how to search for translation and i would have to add both cases:

```
TRANSLATIONS
id   word_id   translation_id
1      1            2
2      2            1
```

Some ideas? I hope my description makes sense.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Another approach could be a table with JSON column like:

```
TRANSLATIONS(id,data)

id                            data
1          {"ro":1,"cs":2,"another_lang": "another_id"}
```

but is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think your database design may be a little off.

Maybe you could have something like :

```
WORD (id,word,language_id,..)
TRANSLATIONS(id,language_id_from,language_id_to,word_id_from,word_id_to)
LANGUAGE(id,code)
```

Then you would have records like:

```
    LANGUAGES
id  code
1   EN (english)
2   RO (romanian)

      WORDS
id    word   language_id
221   hi     1
4423  Bună   2


TRANSLATIONS

id      lang_id_from   lang_id_to   word_id_from   word_id_to
54512         1             2             221          4423
```

Then, for a given word in a given language, such as **"hi"** in english, you would look for the translations record that matches the id of the word (**1**) and target the language id you're looking for, such as Romanian (**2**).

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Translations 
WHERE word_id_from = 1 AND language_id_to = 2
```

And it would be scalable, because you can add new languages, words and translations as you want, and your search wouldn't be affected.

Comment: But in case I would want to translate Buna to hi I need another row in table TRANSLATIONS: `54513   2   1   4423 221`. And I don't think I need `lang_id_from` and `lang_id_to` columns, because I can get to the language through `word_id_from` and `word_id_to` columns.

Comment: You are assuming a 1:1 correspondence between the words in the source language and the target language. The more languages you add, the harder this fiction will be to maintain. For example the English word driver has 4 translations in Dutch depending on whether he is driving a car, a tram, a bus or a train. But only 3 in French.

Comment: You're right, lang_id_from and lang_id_to are not necessary. But you have to thing long term. Maybe in matters of performance you prefer to have the language ID's right in your translations table. In NO-SQL databases such as MongoDB, oriented for web applications it's more likely that you do.

Comment: And to BoarGules: I don't think I assumed that correspondence. The Translations table does the multiple relation possible. You could add as many translations for the same word as you want. In any language, even if the language repeats itself. I apologize if I wasn't clear about that. In his query, he would get all of the translations for the word in the target language. In your example, he would get 4 records by searching the Dutch translation, and 3 records in French.